# Can someone point me to a good Vi (or Vim) app for windows?

Tags: vim, ide, editor, text-editor

I've been inspired by yehuda katz (
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/29/everyone-who-tried-to-convince-me-to-use-vim-was-wrong/ ) to start using Vi (or vim) as opposed to my current tool of choice, Notepad++.

I had a look on the vim.org site but couldn't find any recent windows vim app, am i looking in the wrong place or something? Or is there truly not a modern vim windows app?

Can people recommend something along the lines of MacVIM for Windows?

Thanks

Comment: In the spirit of ykatz's recommendation, be sure you include the `behave mswin` and `source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` statements in your `_vimrc` file. They make Vim a lot more friendly to Windows users. See `:help mswin.vim` and `:help :behave` for more information.

Comment: Thanks bill! that'll be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the link to the download:

ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim72.exe

It includes both the command line and GUI version for Win32.

Here are some settings for your vimrc file that make it a little more civilized for programming tasks:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set number
set nowrap
set nobackup
set nohlsearch
"set gfn=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 12
"colorscheme asc
syntax on
```

I commented out my font and custom color scheme.  Salt to taste....

Comment: I'd suggest you take out `expandtab` and `softtabstop` and replace them with `set confirm`.

Answer (score 4):

It's listed under "MS-DOS and Windows", but [gvim72.exe](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim72.exe) is what you're looking for.  That's the latest and greatest, official, graphical Vim.

Comment: Second this! gvim is the my default editor on ALL the platforms I work with!

Comment: How about 'Cream' - anyone use that?

Answer (score 3):

[Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) is VIM modded to be more user friendly. It might be a good starting point. If not, they have a good Windows [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim) that is raw VIM too.

Comment: I always use cream packaging as it is (almost) always compiled with the latest patches. However, I do never use cream itself, nor the msvim aberration, as I like gvim as it is: a unix tool.

Comment: I enjoy using cream because I get all the power underlying (g)vim, plus the de facto standard keystrokes for cut, copy, paste, and undo. And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Because Source Forge is no longer a trusted source for programs, where should we go to get Cream now?  Is there some precaution that should be used to prevent malicious code installation from Source Forge?

Answer (score 0):

Care to try [gvim](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim72.exewant.)?

From the [download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc):

> For Vim 6 and later. This includes a
>   GUI version of Vim - with many
>   features and OLE support - and all the
>   runtime files. It works well on
>   MS-Windows 95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP. Use
>   this if you have enough disk space and
>   memory. It's the simplest way to start
>   using Vim on the PC. The installer
>   allows you to skip the parts you don't
>   want.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have yet the option to comment on the accepted answer : yes, *gvim*, of course, also and quite importantly if you move around, *there's a portable flavour for **Portable Apps***.

(You can also install cygwin, but that's a different use case)